# Where is this white space coming from in IE11?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

All right, I'm really stumped, so I'm turning to you guys for help.

I have this website (http://accofin.be/) that I recently developed, but for some reason, in IE11, there's a gigantic white gap on the homepage just before the footer.

I've tried all the possible solutions that used to work to fix the common problems for IE11, but to no avail.

One thing I did notice is that the issue disappears when you were to remove the `.home-articles` block, then everything is layout as it should.

Any clue?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Like I said, I can only pinpoint the block (`.home-articles`) that I *think* holds the problem. If I were to be able to really isolate the issue, I hope I would've found a solution myself.

Comment: @JDansercoer Without a [mcve], this question will almost certainly get closed, in which case you _definitely_ won't get the help you want.

Comment: If you right click a node in the DOM Explorer, you can click "Copy element with styles". It is perhaps not as difficult as you think it is... Also, you say you developed it, so I would think you'd have the source code...

Comment: It's just, I've done the exact same approach that I've done in a multitude of other websites, however, in this example, there's this huge white space that I can't explain at all. So, for the life of it, I can **not** pinpoint the exact problem.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I've had my element inspector open for the last two hours, been fiddling around with the styles, been editing and deleting classes on my localhost, but for the life of it I just can't figure it out. I know I seem like a beginner for the wording of my question, but I've been working with CSS for 10 years now, which is why I'm really stumped by this issue..

Comment: @JDansercoer I was testing it, and it's not the `.home-articles` element. It's the last of your `div` inside your `main` element. I tried to change its order by moving (not deleting) the `.home-articles` element above others and it still shows that gap. I still don't know why, sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is related with **Display:flex;** Which is applied on **body**.

see the testing result with IE 11.

[image]

So I hope this will help you to know that from where that space was came. Further, You can try to modify your code to fix this issue for IE.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the cleanest solution but if you put:

```
body main{
    height: 215vh;
}
```

and remove the margin-top from your footer this appears to resolve the issue, as you can then position the footer using the visual height.